# Check and assign value of a PHP object property within an conditional

Tags: php

Would the following work in PHP:

```
if ($test = $object->property) {
  // Do stuff with $test
}
```

Basically, PHP will still spit out notices even if $object->property isn't set.  I want to see if it's possible to check to see if the value is set and assign a property to a variable within a conditional.  Otherwise, I would have to do something like this:

```
if (isset($object->property) {
  $test = $object->property;
  // Do stuff with $test
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (isset($object->property) ? $test = $object->property : false) {
  // Do stuff with $test
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just better in general to do it the second way. Also because you'll get problems if `$object->property` is a falsy value.

Answer (score 0):

All elements inside `(` `)` are tested from left to right. If one is false the following ones are not tested so you will no have any error.

```
if ($object && is_object($object) && isset($object->property))
{
    $test = $object->property;
    // Do stuff with $test
}
```

---

EDIT: Rechecking your question: you want assign `$object->property` inside the parentheses! I ask you `why so anxious?` That construction is nice (I use it very often) but do it when make things simpler not the opposite!